# LINQ Find String Duplicates in List

Tags: regex, string, linq, filter, duplicates

I am trying to prevent name duplicates in a List, but with no luck so far.
I have a list of entries and each entry has a name (**e.g. entries:** "*file*", "*file1*", "*someFile*", "*anotherFile*"). Whenever I create new entry I add it to the entry List. But I don't want to add new entry with the same name.
I have a file that I just created (**e.g. name:** "*file*"). 
How do I find all name duplicates and make it something like this at the end: "*file2*"?

Sorry if the question is a bit vague.
I tried to use **LINQ** and **Regex**, but I'm kind of new to those things so not sure what I'm doing..

Comment: You need to at least show some code of what you tried... consider `List<string>.Contains`.

Comment: I don't have much to show I just looked around the net about LINQ and Regex, but nothing I tried did the trick, so at the end I just have a bunch of messy and nonsensical code..

Comment: Add in the question whatever you have tried to give us the clue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to what you have posted in question a simple program with if-else conditions could solve your problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] entries = new []{"file", "file1", "someFile", "anotherFile", "file", "someFile", "file"};
        List<string> curatedEntries = new List<string>();

        foreach(string e in entries)
        {
            int index = 0;
            string entry = e;
            Check:
            if(CheckExists(curatedEntries, entry)){
                index++;
                entry = e + index;
                goto Check;
            }

            curatedEntries.Add(entry);
        }
        curatedEntries.ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x));
    }

    public static bool CheckExists(List<string> lst,string e)
    {
        return lst.Any(x=>x.Equals(e));
    }
}
```

Here's fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fdSClH